# How to format this output into an array/useable data

Tags: python

I'm not a coder by trade, rather an infrastructure engineer that's learning to code for my role. I have an output that I am getting and I am struggling to think how I can get this to work.

I've utilized some of my colleagues but the data is outputted in a weird format and I am unsure how to get the outcome I want. I have tried splitting the lines but it will not work perfectly.

The current code is simple. It just pulls the output command from the switch & I then have it split the lines:

```py
output = net_connect.send_command("show switch")
switchlines = output.splitlines()
print(output)
print(switchlines[5])
```

It will then output the following in this case:

```
Switch/Stack Mac Address : 188b.45ea.a000 - Local Mac Address
Mac persistency wait time: Indefinite
                                             H/W   Current
Switch#   Role    Mac Address     Priority Version  State 
------------------------------------------------------------
*1       Active   188b.45ea.a000     15     V01     Ready               
 2       Standby  00ca.e5fc.1780     14     V06     Ready               
 3       Member   00ca.e5fc.5e80     13     V06     Ready               
 4       Member   00ca.e588.f480     12     V06     Ready               
 5       Member   00ca.e588.ee80     11     V06     Ready               


*1       Active   188b.45ea.a000     15     V01     Ready
```

That table comes out as a string & essentially, I need to find a way to split that into usable chunks (I.E a 2D Array) So I can use each field individually.

Answer (score 1):

You already got the lines separated in a list (`switchlines`), so all you have left to do is iterate over that list and [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) each one on spaces. Because there are many spaces separating, we also want to [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) those elements. So you could do something like:

```py
res = []

for line in switchlines[5:]:
    elements = [x.strip() for x in line.split()]
    res.append(elements)
```

And this gives on your example text:

```
[['*1', 'Active', '188b.45ea.a000', '15', 'V01', 'Ready'],
 ['2', 'Standby', '00ca.e5fc.1780', '14', 'V06', 'Ready'], 
 ['3', 'Member', '00ca.e5fc.5e80', '13', 'V06', 'Ready'], 
 ['4', 'Member', '00ca.e588.f480', '12', 'V06', 'Ready'], 
 ['5', 'Member', '00ca.e588.ee80', '11', 'V06', 'Ready']]
```

---

Another option that can later help you work on the data, is collect it into a dictionary instead of a list:

```py
for line in switchlines[5:]:
    switch, role, mac, prio, ver, state, *extras = [x.strip() for x in line.split()]
    res.append({'switch': switch, 'role': role, 'mac': mac,
                'prio': prio, 'ver': ver, 'state': state, 'extras': extras})
```

And this gives on your example text:

```
[{'switch': '*1', 'role': 'Active', 'mac': '188b.45ea.a000', 'prio': '15', 'ver': 'V01', 'state': 'Ready', 'extras': []},
 {'switch': '2', 'role': 'Standby', 'mac': '00ca.e5fc.1780', 'prio': '14', 'ver': 'V06', 'state': 'Ready', 'extras': []},
 {'switch': '3', 'role': 'Member', 'mac': '00ca.e5fc.5e80', 'prio': '13', 'ver': 'V06', 'state': 'Ready', 'extras': []},
 {'switch': '4', 'role': 'Member', 'mac': '00ca.e588.f480', 'prio': '12', 'ver': 'V06', 'state': 'Ready', 'extras': []},
 {'switch': '5', 'role': 'Member', 'mac': '00ca.e588.ee80', 'prio': '11', 'ver': 'V06', 'state': 'Ready', 'extras': []}]
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this. It's rather helpful and has got me on the right track. I am getting a error with the dictionary however: 

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 6, got 0)

Trying to work through that and will do so, but any quick ideas?

Comment: That might be because some lines are shorter. I misunderstood your error at first, so I edited my question to support in case of longer lines. The error you're describing is because of shorter lines. These require specific handling. Also, if your rows might have missing values, for example one line only missing the Role field, I am affraid to say that my solution will fail and probably pandas will be a better solution